# Delay in receiving emails

Tags: gmail-api

Currently, we are using one Gmail API to receive MFA through Email. We are using this in automated tests to read to code.Until yesterday we are receiving emails in seconds and we are able to read the code. But starting from today there is some delay in receiving an Email and sometimes the email is not been received.

Is there any way to check these logs? Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you experienced some delay, based on this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota#mail_sending_limits) there can be a delay of several minutes if the user exceeds their quota. You can also try to use the [`Users.messages: get`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) to get the specific message and check if it has some delay in receiving.

I found here a related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715820/gmail-api-quickest-method-to-check-for-new-mail) about your problem. So just check it if it can help you. It uses [`IMAP`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/pop_imap_settings#imap) for this issue.